# Consulta SQL lineal sin importar campos, ¿es posible?

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Es posible realizar una consulta, la cuál creé columnas automáticamente según los datos, sin importar la condición?

Me explico:

Tengo una tabla de encuestas, otra tabla que contiene las preguntas que se hacen por encuestas y otras las respuestas que se hacen a las preguntas por encuesta. Esto bueno, va con el usuario que la hace, a quién se la hace y demás...

Hay una tabla que se llama `Encuestas Realizadas`, allí es donde se guardan. Por decirlo de cierta forma, las transacciones por encuesta que se hace.

Cuando se hace una encuesta, esta tabla, y la de respuestas, son las que se llenan.

Ahora:

Necesito un informe en el cual se evidencie, por `Transacción` (encuesta que se realice), el `id` de la encuesta, su nombre, pregunta y respuesta.

Hasta ahí todo normal, se puede hacer con sus `select` e `inner joins`, pero ahora me dicen, ***¿Es posible que el informe de pregunta - respuesta se haga horizontal y no verticalmente?***.

Es decir:

La consulta que tengo ya hace el informe verticalmente:

```
ID_EncuestaRealizada | ID_Encu | Encuesta | Id Pregu | Pregunta | ID Res | Respues | Fecha

    00001 | 1 | Encuesta 1 | 1 | Pregunta 1 |  2 | Si | 2017-18-05 12:00:00
    00001 | 1 | Encuesta 1 | 2 | Pregunta 2 |  2 | Si | 2017-18-05 12:00:20
    00001 | 1 | Encuesta 1 | 3 | Pregunta 3 |  3 | No | 2017-18-05 12:00:49
    00002 | 3 | Encuesta 3 | 1 | Pregunta 1 |  1 | 5 | 2017-18-05 12:00:00
    00002 | 3 | Encuesta 3 | 2 | Pregunta 2 |  2 | Si | 2017-18-05 12:00:20
    00002 | 3 | Encuesta 3 | 3 | Pregunta 3 |  3 | No | 2017-18-05 12:00:49
    00002 | 3 | Encuesta 3 | 4 | Pregunta 4 |  2 | Si | 2017-18-05 12:00:49
```

Ahora bien, **para mí, creo que es imposible mostrar, en el caso de este ejemplo, en solo dos filas**, ya que uno, las preguntas no son las mismas y **por encuesta puede haber mayor o menor número de preguntas**.

Es decir, quieren más o menos algo así.

```
00001 | 1 | Encuesta 1 | 1 | Pregunta 1 | 2 | Si | 2 | Pregunta 2 | 2 | Si | 3 | Pregunta 3 | 3 | No |        
00002 | 3 | Encuesta 3 | 1 | Pregunta 1 | 1 | 5 | 2  | Pregunta 2 | 2 | Si | 3 | Pregunta 3 | 3 | No | 4 | Pregunta 4 | 2 | Si |
```

> **Consulta SQL que tengo**

```
 SELECT 
 ENREA.Id_EncuestaRealizada
,ENREA.UserName
,EN.Id_Encuesta
,EN.Nombre
,ENRES.Id_Pregunta
,PRE.Pregunta
,ENRES.Id_Respuesta
,RESP.Respuesta
,ENRES.RespuestaNumerica
,ENRES.RespuestaNumerica
,ENRES.RespuestaAbierta
,ENRES.Comentarios
FROM [dbo].[tbl_encuestasrealizadas] ENREA
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_encuestasrespuesta] ENRES ON ENRES.Id_EncuestaRealizada = ENREA.Id_EncuestaRealizada
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_encuestas] EN ON EN.Id_Encuesta = ENREA.Id_Encuesta
INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_preguntas] PRE ON PRE.Id_Pregunta = ENRES.Id_Pregunta AND PRE.Id_Encuesta = ENREA.Id_Encuesta
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl_respuestalistas] RESP ON RESP.Id_Respuesta = ENRES.Id_Respuesta
WHERE EN.Id_Campana = 1;
```

Eso me devuelve una tabla así (Para mi, así está bien)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este muestro tres encuestas diferentes, puede que por coincidencia algunas encuestas tengan el mismo número de preguntas, pero no es exacto, eso es variable, **pueden ser n número de preguntas por encuestas**.

Para mi sigue siendo imposible hacer eso.

Comment: No estoy seguro de que se pueda, y nunca lo he intentando pero me parece que lo que necesitas es convertir columnas en filas, y PIVOT y UNPIVOT te podría ayudar siguiendo este articulo https://revistadigital.inesem.es/informatica-y-tics/convertir-filas-en-columnas-y-columnas-en-filas-en-sql-server/

Comment: Umm dejame leerlo, parece que si se podria jaja

Comment: Según lo que entendí de lo que quieres hacer y lo que leí en ese articulo creo que si se puede, ojala te funcione.

Comment: Pero según veo, tendría que quemar los datos o cómo seria en el caso de preguntas respuestas, porque en el articulo usan años, pero el llena con los datos 2006 hasta el 2010 para que le aparezcan, ¿tendría que quemar los ID de las preguntas en la consulta?

Comment: Cualquier select en SQL devuelve una cantidad de columnas fija. No es el caso del ejemplo que pones. Así que no, no se puede. A menos que uno tenga un numero fijo de preguntas por encuesta.

Comment: Agregaré la consulta que tengo hecha

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que podrías utilizar la función `STUFF` y `FOR XML PATH` de esta forma, no sé si es como lo deseas, pero esta es mi idea:

```
SELECT
    STUFF(
    (SELECT 
        ', [ENCUESTA REALIZADA:' + ENREA.Id_EncuestaRealizada + ', USUARIO:' + ENREA.UserName + ', ENCUESTA:' + EN.Id_Encuesta + ']'
    FROM [dbo].[tbl_encuestasrealizadas] ENREA
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_encuestasrespuesta] ENRES ON ENRES.Id_EncuestaRealizada = ENREA.Id_EncuestaRealizada
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_encuestas] EN ON EN.Id_Encuesta = ENREA.Id_Encuesta
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[tbl_preguntas] PRE ON PRE.Id_Pregunta = ENRES.Id_Pregunta
        AND PRE.Id_Encuesta = ENREA.Id_Encuesta
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[tbl_respuestalistas] RESP ON RESP.Id_Respuesta = ENRES.Id_Respuesta
    WHERE EN.Id_Campana = 1 AND ENREA.Id_EncuestaRealizada = ER.Id_EncuestaRealizada FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS RESULTADOS
FROM
    [dbo].[tbl_encuestasrealizadas] AS ER
```

No estoy seguro si funciones la consulta, pero es mi idea de lo que necesitas.